# Cannot upload 1GB file to Amazon S3 via PHP Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, amazon-s3

I have a PHP form which takes a selected zip file on submit and uses AJAX to post to an Amazon S3 bucket.  This process goes great when I test 10MB or less zip files, but when I test something over 500MB I get the following error:

```
Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.
```

I need to be able to allow up to 5GB zip files to be uploaded.  At this point I need a better understanding of what I need to do to allow the users to upload large files.  Any help is much appreciated.

PS:  I will be happy to add code snippets, but I am looking to get a response to show the necessary snippets rather than posting a bunch of unrelated code.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884683/browser-uploads-to-s3-with-instance-roles) will be helpful to you. It discusses uploads directly to S3 but with authorisation done in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should increase the `post_max_size` variable in the php.ini file (or use ini_set()) which is set at 10MB by default if i remember well. You should also have a look on the `upload_max_filesize` variable and `max_execution_time` because i guess it takes a long time to upload 5GB...

If your issue is JQuery/Ajax related, may be you should consider using a FormData object.

[Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Thank you, I will look into these options and see if they offer the solution.

Comment: The only thing that concerns me about this is the way I am using AJAX to bypass our servers with the upload...  Either way I will test this and update the question with my results.

Comment: I have attempted 15MB and 30MB packages and they work great.  I will research these other links and see if that opens up any options to test.

Answer (score 0):

OK, in the end I had to use the Amazon SDK for chunking large files.  This breaks up the file into multiple pieces and therefore prevents the server timeout.